# Is it possible to embed an iframe element in a fabricjs canvas to insert a youtube video into it?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube, fabricjs

I need to embed a youtube video in a fabricjs canvas. I have tried to do this by inserting an iframe element into a fabricjs image object. This has worked for me to insert a  element into the canvas before. However, when inserting an iframe it is not possible.

```
<input type="text" name="enlace-video" id="enlace-video-yt"  value="" placeholder="http://">
<button id="input-video-yt">
    Insert YT video
</button>
```

```
const ytVideo = document.getElementById('input-video-yt');
ytVideo.addEventListener('click', function (){

    var ytvideoURL = document.getElementById("enlace-video-yt").value;
    var embedURL = ytvideoURL.replace("watch?v=","embed/");

    var divVideo = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(divVideo);

    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.id="new-video";
    iframe.src = embedURL;
    divVideo.appendChild(iframe);

    iframe.addEventListener( "loadedmetadata", function (e) {
        
        var fab_video = new fabric.Image(iframe, {left: 100,   top: 50, data: "video"});
        canvas.add(fab_video);

    }, false );
});
```

Any other way that makes it possible to insert a youtube video into the canvas would work for me.

Answer (score 1):

To add YouTube Video in canvas,
you will need to create a video html tag and assign source to YouTube video link, and then add that video in Canvas as shown in

> Demo: http://fabricjs.com/video-element

Comment: Can you share working code with Youtube video?

Comment: I have tried to do that but I get a Cross-Origin Read Blocking error. Have you managed to insert a youtube video into fabricjs?